# Calculate overlap between binary variables

Tags: r, correlation

I'm trying to calculate how many people play different combinations of sports. I know how to calculate and plot the correlation, but I'd like to get the actual numbers of how many people fall into each combined group.

Here's a simplified demo of my data. A `1` means a given person plays the given sport, and a `0` means she does not.

```
    sports_example <- tibble(
      name = c(
        "Scarlett",
        "Heather",
        "Sarah",
        "Anna",
        "Emma",
        "Charlotte",
        "Cheryl"
      ),
      hockey = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L),
      basketball = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L),
      track = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L),
      football = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)
    )
```

Using the code below, I can calculate the correlations between different sports. I can tell that hockey shares more players with basketball than football. But I'd like to calculate *how many* athletes play both hockey and basketball (3 in this case). Is there an easy algorithm for counting the overlap? My real dataset has dozens of columns, so my one-off code isn't cutting it (e.g. `nrow(filter(sports_example, hockey + basketball == 2))`).

```
sports_example %>% 
  select(-name) %>% 
  cor() %>% 
  corrgram::corrgram(upper.panel = NULL)
```

[image: Correlation plot of Andrew's demo data]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For pairwise results, you can calculate the matrix cross product of the binary variables, then set the upper triangle and diagonal to zero so we can filter to keep only the unique pairs.

```
res <- crossprod(as.matrix(sports_example[-1]))
res[upper.tri(res, diag = TRUE)] <- 0
subset(as.data.frame.table(res), Freq > 0)

         Var1       Var2 Freq
2  basketball     hockey    3
3       track     hockey    4
4    football     hockey    1
7       track basketball    3
8    football basketball    1
12   football      track    1
```

Comment: Lots of great answers, but I picked yours because it's the most flexible approach and it seems to work equally well no matter how I change my underlying data. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest next approach where you can identify what happens for all players:

```
library(reshape2)
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)

#Data
sports_example <- tibble(
  name = c(
    "Scarlett",
    "Heather",
    "Sarah",
    "Anna",
    "Emma",
    "Charlotte",
    "Cheryl"
  ),
  hockey = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L),
  basketball = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L),
  track = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L),
  football = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)
)

#Reshape
Melted <- melt(sports_example,id.vars = 'name')
```

After reshaping you could group and aggregate with `dplyr` functions:

```
#Now filter and compute
Melted %>% group_by(name) %>% filter(variable %in% c('hockey','basketball')) %>% 
  summarise(N=sum(value))
```

It will result in:

```
# A tibble: 7 x 2
  name          N
  <chr>     <int>
1 Anna          1
2 Charlotte     2
3 Cheryl        1
4 Emma          1
5 Heather       2
6 Sarah         2
7 Scarlett      1
```

Then you can add a new filter to reach what you want:

```
#Now filter and compute 2
Melted %>% group_by(name) %>% filter(variable %in% c('hockey','basketball')) %>% 
  summarise(N=sum(value)) %>% filter(N==2)
```

The output:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  name          N
  <chr>     <int>
1 Charlotte     2
2 Heather       2
3 Sarah         2
```

Then, you also can identify players and the number you wish.

Answer (score 1):

How about `count()`?

```
count(sports_example, hockey, basketball)
##   hockey basketball     n
##    <int>      <int> <int>
## 1      0          1     1
## 2      1          0     3
## 3      1          1     3
```

Or

```
(count(sports_example, hockey, basketball) 
   %>% filter(hockey==1, basketball==1)
   %>% pull(n)
)
```

The base-R version would be something like

```
with(sports_example, as.data.frame(table(hockey,basketball)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the data in long format, keep rows only for `value = 1`, create pairing combination for each `name` and `count` them.

```
library(dplyr)

sports_example %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = -name, names_to = 'col') %>%
  filter(value == 1) %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  summarise(val = if(n() > 1) combn(col, 2, function(x) 
                     sort(toString(x))) else col) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  count(val)

#  val                      n
#  <chr>                <int>
#1 basketball, football     1
#2 basketball, track        3
#3 hockey                   1
#4 hockey, basketball       3
#5 hockey, football         1
#6 hockey, track            4
#7 track, football          1
```

This answer will work for `dplyr` > 1.0.0 which allows to return multiple rows in `summarise`.

Answer (score 0):

You can vectorize:

```
(sports_example$hockey & sports_example$basketball) %>% sum
```